# Cannot use an 'if statment' on the output of a fucntion, with a single-valued return, inisde a loop. (Use a.any() or a.all() error)

Tags: python, numpy, function, if-statement, nested-loops

First time asking a question here.

The following code is supposed to plot the 'neutron drip line' of nuclei. It represents, fir each specific value of atomic number (Z), the limiting value of neutron number(N) beyond which the addition of a neutron would render the nuclei unstable. The instability is signified by the separation energy turning negative where separation energy refers to the difference in binding energy values of (Z,N) and (Z,N+1) combinations. I used the following steps to achieve the same:

1. Create an array of Z values and N values from a list of A values. I defined a `zmin()` function to obtain value of Z and taking the difference with A to obtain the value of N.
2. Take a Z value and calculate the binding energy of a series N values in increment until the separation between (Z,N) and (Z,N+1) combination returns a negative value. Append the value of N for which this occurs and move onto the next Z value, until the end of the list.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

avol = 15.5  # Initializing the coefficients
asurf = 16.8
acol = 0.72
asym = 23

def bind_en (Z, N):  #Defining a function to calculate binding energy 
                    #curve using semi-emperical mass formulae
    if ((Z+N)%2)!=0 and (Z%2)==0:
        apar=0
    elif ((Z+N)%2)==0 and (Z%2)!=0:
        apar=0
    elif ((Z+N)%2)==0 and (Z%2)==0:
        apar=34
    elif ((Z+N)%2)!=0 and (Z%2)!=0:
        apar=-34
          
    b = avol*(Z+N)-asurf*((Z+N)**(2/3))-(acol*Z*(Z-1))/((Z+N)**(1/3))-asym*(((Z+N)-2*Z)**2)/(Z+N)+apar/((Z+N)**(3/4))  
    
    return b/A

def zmin(A):
    z = (A / 2) * (1 / (1 + 0.25 * (A ** (2 / 3)) * (acol / asym)))
    z = int(z)
    return z

A = np.arange(1, 261, 1)
Z = []
N = []
NM=[]

for i in range(len(A)):
    Z.append(zmin(A[i]))
    N.append(A[i]-Z[i])

flag=False

for j in range(len(Z)):
    for k in range(len(N)):
        s=bind_en(Z[j],N[k+1])-bind_en(Z[j],N[k])
        '''if isinstance(s, np.ndarray):
            print("s is an array.")'''
        if s<0:
            NM.append(N[k])
            flag=True
            break         
    if flag:
        break

plt.plot(NM, Z)
plt.xlabel('Number of Neutrons (N)')
plt.ylabel('Number of Protons (Z)')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

On execution, this error shows up:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[27], line 45
     42 s=bind_en(Z[j],N[k+1])-bind_en(Z[j],N[k])
     43 '''if isinstance(s, np.ndarray):
     44     print("s is an array.")'''
---> 45 if s<0:
     46     NM.append(N[k])
     47     flag=True

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I understand that the meaning of this error is that the 's' variable is an array (the commented `isinstance()` function does verify the same, and therefore it cannot be compared with the single value 0.

But I don't understand how it can be an array. Is there any way to fix it, please?

Comment: Do not mix general Python programming with numpy or pandas programming such as using `if` and `for` loops on arrays or data frames and not vectorizing operations but instead looping across element values.

Answer (score 2):

A is an array defined as:

```
A = np.arange(1, 261, 1)
```

Therefore when your function `bind_en` returns `return b/A` where `b` is a number, the result is also an array - each element of A is used as a divider to `b` and the new array is formed of the results.

If you are expecting a number as a results, a whole array should not be a part of the calculations. I am not sure of the maths behind your code, but for other arrays you use indices to choose a certain element (for example `bind_en(Z[j],N[k+1])`), perhaps you can do it with `A` too?
Otherwise aggregation functions can be considered (for example `sum(A)`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your bind_en function:

```py
def bind_en (Z, N):
    ... code
    b = ....

    print(type(b)) # <class 'numpy.float64'>
    print(type(A)) # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
    print(type(b/A)) # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
 
    return b/A
```

You return b/A. The type of b/A is an numpy array, which can not be compared to integer 0.